# React - passing props to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components

I can't seem to get it to work. all i need is to pass a single value, selectedCategory. the error i'm getting:

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'passSelectedCategory') (in the child component)

Child:

```
const CategoryWindow =(props)=> {
    const categories = ["h", "a", "s", "o"]

    return (
        <div className="categories-div">
                {categories.map(category => 
                    <button className={"category-btn " + `${category}`}
                        key={category}
                        value={category}
                        onClick={props.passSelectedCategory(selectedCategory)}       <----
                    >
                            <h2>{category}</h2>
                    </button>
                    )}
                
        </div>
    )
}
```

parent:

```
const Main =()=> {
    const [showElement, setShowElement] = useState([1][0][0]);
    const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState();

    return (
    <>
        <main className="main">
            <div>
                <div>
                     <CategoryWindow
                         passSelectedCategory={setSelectedCategory}   <---
                     />
                </div>
                .....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass `category` as a parameter at the `props.passSelectedCategory` ( the child component, `CategoryWindow` doesn't have the visibility of the `selectedCategory` variable)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <button className={"category-btn " + `${category}`}
                        key={category}
                        value={category}
                        onClick={() => props.passSelectedCategory(category)}
                    >
                            <h2>{category}</h2>
                    </button>
```

Everything in your code is perfect you just need to change your onClick function as I mentioned above.